# Tax questions and understanding my paystub

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-4, form-w-2

I work for a bar that opened a couple months ago. I did not even fill out an application or any TAX forns etc. I received my 1st paycheck after I gave my boss my SSN. I received the check connected to the other two things I needed like year to date etc. I can barely understand it and maybe I am wrong but seems like things are missing.

1st off How do they calculate or deductions if you haven't computed tax papers?

Been there since August n the rate of pay is $6 hourly and I have not once reported my actual tips and were to claim $50 per pay period atleast if you didn't make it.

When I receive these stubs I question them and I don't get it how they just do it for me?

Another issue is on my last check that I noticed which might not be bad is; I have a overtime box and says I have an overtime rate at $9.63 and I am not sure for what. But in my totals box it says

- 78.00 hrs × $6.00 is $468
- Plus reported tips $239 (I have never reported any) which = $707.00
- minus deductions are of $146.75. Not sure what they are
- Net Amount of $321.25 [This is what I deposited]

But not anywhere on the year to date stub does it say anything about that $9.63 Rate?
And every check is different and If the reported tips is incorrect, do I get a % back at taxes for tips? Or how does that work?

Also, in my deductions box I have what's being deducted like:
FICA--SS    >  $43.84
FICA--MED   >  $10.25
FIT         >  $72.66
IOWA--SIT   >  $20.00

And this is what my deductions were earlier. What is the FIT one?
Again I never filled out a W-4 Form or any paperwork for that matter until the last day in December.

So how do they know allowances, filling status etc.

So many questions about every weeks stub but I just wanted to calculate my W-2 or know what stub to turn in for when I file.

Answer (score 6):

I will handle your questions point-by-point:

> Plus reported tips $239 (I have never reported any)

If you are working in a position that you collect tips, some of the tips you receive are from people that pay via debit card or credit card. Many of them include the tip on the charge slip. The management then credits the employee with those tips. You might also receive a portion of other tips for example some establishments credit a portion of tips to busboys and hosts.

> minus deductions are of $146.75. Not sure what they are... Also, in my
>   deductions box I have what's being deducted like:
>
> - FICA--SS  $43.84
> - FICA--MED $10.25
> - FIT $72.66
> - IOWA--SIT  $20.00

Those 4 items are your deductions.

- FICA--SS  $43.84 = Social security (6.2% of everything you make up to $127,200 per year)
- FICA--MED $10.25  = Medicare (1.45% of everything you make)
- FIT $72.66 = Federal Income tax.
- IOWA--SIT  $20.00 = Iowa State income tax.

> I have a overtime box and says I have an overtime rate at $9.63 and I
>   am not sure for what
>
> But not anywhere on the year to date stub does it say anything about
>   that $9.63 Rate?

The $9.63 is an overtime rate. If in one of your pay periods you worked more than 40 hours in a week, they would have paid you that higher rate for those extra hours. Many times the Year-to-Bate boxes only have totals, and don't tell you how many hours were at which rate.

> And every check is different and If the reported tips is incorrect, do
>   I get a % back at taxes for tips? Or how does that work?

You should be keeping track of all the cash tips you receive. The company doesn't have any information about them. You will have to declare those cash tips when you file your federal and state taxes this spring.

Talk to your employer regarding tips. This is a big issue they should be collecting from you a monthly summary of cash tips, their count of credit card tips, and any shared tips.  The tax impact is on both of you because they have to collect FICA from your paycheck, and they also have to pay their portion.

See [IRS Publication 531 (2016), Reporting Tip Income](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p531/)

> How to report.   If your employer does not give you any other way to
>   report your tips, you can use Form 4070, Employee's Report of Tips to
>   Employer. Fill in the information asked for on the form, sign and date
>   the form, and give it to your employer. A sample filled-in Form 4070
>   is shown above. To get a 1-year supply of the form, ask the IRS or
>   your employer for Pub. 1244.
>
> If you do not use Form 4070, give your employer a statement with the
>   following information.
>
> - Your name, address, and social security number.
> - Your employer's name, address, and business name (if it is different from your employer's name).
> - The month (or the dates of any shorter period) in which you received tips.
> - The total tips required to be reported for that period.
>
> You must sign and date the statement. Be sure to keep a copy with your
>   tax or other personal records.
>
> Your employer may require you to report your tips more than once a
>   month. However, the statement cannot cover a period of more than 1
>   calendar month.

The IRS even has a copy of the form you can use.

> Again I never filled out a W-4 Form or any paperwork for that matter
>   until the last day in December.
>
> So how do they know allowances, filling status etc.
>
> So many questions about every weeks stub but I just wanted to
>   calculate my W-2 or know what stub to turn in for when I file.

They should have collected this information from you to be able to withhold the taxes correctly. Though keep in mind correctly from their standpoint means that they followed the tax tables and other calculations, not that you will receive a refund in the spring.

Every company I have ever worked for has collected the W-4 info on day one. I would not expect that they would want to guess the correct amounts for you.

The company will generate the W-2 form for you based on the information that equals the numbers on your last pay stub of the year. They will generate the W-2 and send it to you, or make it available to you on a website by the end of January.

Comment: +1, great answer. The only thing I could add is to address tips. There are some jobs that can pay below minimum wage, but they assume you will receive tips. If you don't report anything, they still assume a certain minimum. (I'll delete comment if you add any of this to the answer)